# Electron-builder app show blank screen for 32 bit, but works for 64-bit version

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

```
"package": "yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never",
"package-win-32": "yarn build && electron-builder build --win --ia32",
```

package will create 64-bit version of app. 
package-win-32 create 32-bit version of app.

## 64 bit version

[image: 64-bit Version]

## 32 bit version

[image: 32-bit version]

how to resolve this issue, can anyone help?

Comment: Ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened recently to an app i'm working on. After analyzing the app's crash reports, we found out that a stack overflow error was thrown. The following option seems to have solved the issue for us.

`app.disableHardwareAcceleration();`

Add it to your main, before the creation of the browser window.